# Why it return me errors after I ran SQL statement 'declare' in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table was defined as follow:
[image]

I try to declare a variables in using 'declare',but it always ruturn errors and I don't know why.

the code：

```
mysql> DELEMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE emp_age_count(IN age1 int,IN age2 int,OUT count INT)
        -> BEGIN
        -> DECLARE temp FLOAT;
        -> DECLARE emp_age CURSOR FOR SELECT empage FROM emp;
        -> DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        -> CLOSE emp_age;
        -> SET @sum=0;
        -> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM emp
        -> WHERE empage>age1 AND empage<age2;
        -> OPEN emp_age;
        -> REPEAT
        -> FETCH emp_age INTO temp;
        -> IF temp>age1 AND temp<age2;
        -> THEN SET @sum=@sum+temp;
        -> END IF;
        -> UNTIL 0 END REPEAT;
        -> CLOSE emp_age;
        -> END//


    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
    version for the right syntax to use near ';
    THEN SET @sum=@sum+temp;
    END IF;
    UNTIL 0 END REPEAT;
    CLOSE emp_age;
    END' at line 13
```

Comment: The error tells you where the syntax is wrong, which is not in the variables declaration. You're using a `;` at the end of the first `if` line

Comment: `DELEMITER `? Is this actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the ";" at the end of the 'IF' condition

It should be

```
IF (temp>age1 AND temp<age2)
THEN
SET @sum=@sum+temp;
END IF;
```